# How can I pattern match Option in rust? Current code keeps panicking

Tags: rust

I am working on a simple binary search algorithm in rust. It returns an `Option<usize>` and I am trying to pattern match on the return value. My code currently fails on the `None` path. Its clear to me that I am not using the keyword correctly. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Code and output below.

Code:

```
fn find_index( arr: &[usize], find: usize) -> Option<usize> {
   let length = arr.len();
   let mut half = length / 2;
   let mut hind = length - 1;
   let mut lind = 0;
   let mut current = arr[half];

   while  lind <= hind {
       if current == find {
           return Some(half);
       }
       else if current < find{
           lind = half + 1;
       }
       else if current > find {
           hind = half - 1;
       }
        half = (hind + lind) / 2;
        current = arr[half];
   }
   return None;
}

fn grab_array_index(my_arr : &[usize], find: usize) -> usize{ 
    return my_arr.iter()
    .position(|&x| x == find)
    .unwrap();
}

fn main() 
{
    let mut arr = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];
    let mut find = 3;

    println!("Index of {} is {}", find , grab_array_index(&arr, find));
    match find_index(&arr, find) {
        Some(p) => println!("Here ya go! {}", p),
        None => println!("not in the array >:("),
    }

    arr = vec![1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19];
    find = 17;

    println!("Index of {} is {}", find , grab_array_index(&arr, find));
    match find_index(&arr, find) {
        Some(p) => println!("Here ya go! {}", p),
        None => println!("not in the array >:("),
    }

    arr = vec![1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19];
    find = 18;

    println!("Index of {} is {}", find , grab_array_index(&arr, find));
    match find_index(&arr, find) {
        Some(p) => println!("Here ya go! {}", p),
        None => println!("not in the array >:("),
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Index of 3 is 2
Here ya go! 2
Index of 17 is 8
Here ya go! 8
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', binary_search.rs:27:6
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: It's panicking because it can't find 18 in the array, so `.position` returns None. Calling `unwrap` on `None` will panic. Instead, consider returning an Option and not unwrapping. Not finding an item in an array is a valid possibility!

Comment: Couple follow ups:

1). Isn't that somewhat the point of match? To handle the `None` case and move on? Or am I misunderstanding the use of it. 

2). Is returning `None` at the end of my loop essentially saying that the number is not contained in the array (end of `find_index`)?

TIA!!

Comment: 1) You're not matching on the `position`'s result, so, well, the `None` case is handled inside `unwrap` by panicking. 2) It means that the `return Some(half)` branch is never being hit, so, yes, there's no item with `current == find` - assuming that the `arr` is sorted, of course (otherwise the whole algorithm would not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's panicking because before you call `find_index(&arr, find)` where `find == 18`, you call `grab_array_index` which has a call to `unwrap` in it. Since `18` is not in `arr`, `grab_array_index` panics on the unwrap. Consider having that function return an `Option<usize>` as well by removing the call to `unwrap`.

I'm assuming you're doing this for educational purposes, and as such I recommend checking out the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#2346-2348) for `std`'s binary search when you feel satisfied with your solution to see how they make use of language features to generalize the algorithm and make it more efficient.

Comment: Ahhhh duh! I didn't even look at the `grab_array_index` code. Thanks!!

Comment: For future reference, if you compile with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`, then you can see more information about where the panic occurred to prevent this kind of confusion.

Comment: Yeah I should have read the error message more thoroughly. Thanks!